# How to remove the preference for index.html in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

In my public folder I have the index.html file and my route handler is like this

```
 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   // res.send('index.html');
    if (req.user)
        res.redirect('home');
    else
        res.redirect('login');
 });
```

As you can see , I have commented out the serving of index.html file , but nodejs still serves the index.html from the public directory instead of redirecting to home or login. **But if I remove/rename the index.html file then it works fine**.

So How can I configure nodejs so that it invokes the route handler , not the serve index file on request ?

Answer (score 6):

The [`express.static()` middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) includes an `index` option that allows you to change the default file name.

Or, for your intentions, to disable the feature entirely:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
    index: false
}));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is due to ordering of the app.use , previously it was

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', index);
```

changing this to

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Solves the problem.

Comment: yeah i guess this is more like it, index: false on root, did not seem to work for me